# How to call a defined function with parameters with keyboard short keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I have a table in which i am getting data dynamically. In the table there is an edit button with each record like this

```
<tr>
    .
    .
    .
    //other columns
    <td class="center">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-setting edit" href="javascript:;" onClick = "show( 'account_no',<?php echo $row->account_no;?>)">
            <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>  
            Edit                                            
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This way i am sending parameter to show method of javascript. Now i am using a keyboard shortcut plugin called `shortkeys`. When i press down key it adds a class to tr called `selected`. That's fine i have set it up. Now the problem is that i want to add another shorcut to edit the selected record. Here is the code

```
shortcut.add("Alt+e",function() {
    //???
});
```

When alter + e is clicked i want to call show method with the parameters defined dynamically. for clearification i want to call `show('account_no',<?php echo $row->account_no;?>)`. But i have no idea how i can do it. Is there any suggestion or alternative? if i can simply call it it would be good as though i have just clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have doe it using this code.

```
shortcut.add("Alt+e",function() {
    $('.selected > td > a.edit').trigger('click')
});
```

I am calling click trigger and it is working fine.